# How to parse chinese character using PHP Simple HTML DOM parser?

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

I am trying to parse a chinese website using Simple HTML DOM (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) but facing problem where all the chinese characters parsed became unrecognized symbols.

Example: "星洲網" became "æ˜Ÿæ´²ç¶²"

How to use Simple HTML DOM to parse UTF-8 character? or anything I did wrong in my coding?

Below is my PHP coding:

```
<?php
require_once ("simple_html_dom.php");

$html = file_get_html("http://www.sinchew-i.com");
print $html->plaintext;
?>
```

Comment: Where are you looking at the result? In a browser? On the command line? Does other UTF-8 text work in that same environment?

Comment: @deceze, I viewing the result from my browser, the website display UTF-8 chinese character properly when using the original link, http://www.sinchew-i.com

Comment: Try selecting UTF-8 from the View > Encoding menu in your browser, does that help?

Comment: adding meta tag using header function may solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Check this [Handling unicode](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)